# trigger is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i have a table emppersonal in empdetails database..

i have created a trigger

```
use empdetails;

delimiter $$
create trigger `newtirger` after insert  on `emppersonal` 
for each row begin 
if new.mobile = null
then 
update emppersonal set mobile = '121';
end if;
end $$;
```

my scenario is during insert query if the column mobile is having null then insert 121 in the mobile field..

```
insert into emppersonal(empname,empadddress,mobile,empdob) values('lop1wde','n1agar',null,null) ;
```

but the trigger is not showing me any error and also its not working please help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if new.mobile IS NULL`, not `= NULL`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: null is not equal to another null

Comment: hey i got the solution  use empdetails;

delimiter $$
create trigger `newtirger` before insert  on `emppersonal` 
for each row begin 
if new.mobile is NULL
then 
set new.mobile ='121';
end if;
end $$;

Answer (score 0):

A better way to update an empty value would be using a default value for a column. That way it will be automatically set if `null`.

```
ALTER TABLE emppersonal
CHANGE mobile mobile  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '121';
```

if that is not possible then try

```
delimiter $$
create trigger `newtrigger` before insert on emppersonal
for each row begin 
    set NEW.mobile = if(OLD.mobile IS NULL, '121', OLD.mobile);
end
$$
```

Comment: @user2380844: Use `is null`. I missed that one.

Comment: i am using is null only its showing me Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'emppersonal' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Answer (score 0):

try

```
use empdetails;

delimiter $$
create trigger `newtirger` after insert  on `emppersonal` 
for each row begin 
if new.mobile IS NULL
then 
--modify this line update emppersonal set mobile = '121';
update emppersonal set mobile = '121';
end if;
end $$;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'emppersonal' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. showing me this error

Comment: if new.mobile IS NULL Whether the statement is true